# Shrink and wrap blocks of text to never overflow parent block

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like to always show every text section inside the parent without overflowing and while wrapping vertically and shrinking text size if needed.

Desired responsive behavior:
[image: Desired responsive behavior]

I managed to do this:
[image: What I managed so far]
But don't know, how to handle the text-shrinking part. The size of the text has to somehow be related to the maximum width/height of the individuals blocks.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum... <div>
  <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum... <div>
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.section {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  white-space: pre;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Is something like this possible with HTML and CSS?

Test code snippet:

```css
.section {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  white-space: pre;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
        <div class="parent">
          
          <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>
          <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>
          <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>
          <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>
          <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>
          <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>
          <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>
          <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Well, I think there are two ways to solve this issue using tables with media query or using flexbox with media query too, or just use bootstrap to make this behavior in an easy way.

Comment: There's a `clamp` property for fluid font sizing, but I'm not sure it will be enough for your requirements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp (you can set a min, max and variable size for the font), maybe using a percentage value for the second argument since that's calculated base on its parent's size

Answer (score 0):

Delete `flex-flow: column;` from `.parent`

```css
.section {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  white-space: pre;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  
}
```

```html
        <div class="parent">
          <div class="col">              
           <div class="section"> 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>
          <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>
          <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
          <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>
          <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>
          <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
          <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>
          <div class="section"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
            Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. 
            Sed convallis magna eu sem. 
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis 
            est eligendi optio 
          </div>
          </div>


        </div>
```

Comment: That does not do what I was looking for. I need the main flex axis to be vertical, so the flex-flow: column is necessary. See the link in original post to see my desired behavior.

Comment: it is not possible in your html structure. i edited your html structure. check is this ok?

Comment: The thing is that the number of sections and the text in them are dynamic. So there could be 2 sections or there could be 8 of them (or any "reasonable" number). The code I provided was just exemplary.